# How to interpret the sign of a cepstral coefficient?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, speech-processing, cepstral-analysis

I feel like I've got a decent intuition for what the magnitude of a cepstral coefficient represents (i.e. how much of the signal's energy is contained in harmonics of a given wavelength), but I don't really understand what the sign of the cepstrum represents. I feel like it's important to know since some speech processing applications take the max of the real part of the cepstrum (see [here](http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~elec499/2004b/group11/publications/00759042.pdf)), and I'm wondering if there's a reason why the max is in any way more informative than the min, or if I should instead be taking the max of the absolute value of the cepstrum?

Answer (score 1):

For the zero-th cepstral coefficient, the sign is probably always positive since it represents the average energy of the entire spectrum.

For higher-order coefficients, seeing that the question was first posted in 2017, does the OP maybe already have an answer? Would be interested to learn.